# How to change the email interval for apticron?

Tags: server, apticron

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 12.04 Server. Apticron sends out daily emails when there are updates available. I want to change this to weekly.

I looked at the configuration options in `/etc/apticron/apticron.conf`, but that does not list an option to set a different interval for sending the reminder emails. I also can't see a relevant cronjob to modify.

Can I change the `apticron` email interval?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to change this, you must:

1. Delete the daily cronjob (if it exists)
2. Edit `/etc/cron.d/apticron` settings,

   from:

   ```
    30 * * * * root if test -x /usr/sbin/apticron; then /usr/sbin/apticron --cron; else true; fi
   ```

   to:

   ```
    30 11 * * 0 root if test -x /usr/sbin/apticron; then /usr/sbin/apticron --cron; else true; fi
   ```

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20150830040023/http://www.sysadminworld.com/2012/how-to-run-apticron-only-once-a-week/) has a good walkthrough, and [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) explains cron options well.